# Example divergent series of analytic functions?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

Does there exist a sequence of strictly increasing **analytic** positive functions $a_i : ]-1,1 [\to \mathbb{R}^{>0}$ such that 
$$f (x) = \sum_{i=0}^{+\infty} a_i (x) $$
converges for $x\leq 0$ and diverges for $x>0$?

I was able to prove the existence of such functions if we replace *analytic* by  $\mathcal C^{\infty}$ but I am stuck here.

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $a_k(x) = \frac{e^{kx}}{k^2}$. Then
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{e^{kx}}{k^2}
$$
converges for $x\leq 0$ and diverges for $x>0$.

Comment: What is the value at zero?

Comment: $\pi^2/6$: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem

Comment: But it is irrelevant here. What matters is that it converges.

Comment: I asked because your previous answer divided by zero.

Comment: Yes, you can start summing from $0$ if you take $\tilde a_i=a_{i+1}$.

Comment: (Of course, what I mean is that you wrote $\frac{e^{ix}}{ix } $ before editing)

Comment: Yes yes sorry, bad habit of copy-pasting :D

Comment: Thank you very much! It is clear why it converges for $x <0$, and by $e^x \geq 1+x $ we get the divergence when $x>0$. :D

Comment: $e^{ix}$ is not great notation here, it usually suggests something else